# Making a barplot with known frequencies

Tags: r

Sorry for puting this silly question: I am reading the book "Using R for Introductory Statistics" and  would like to create a barplot using this data

```
install.packages("UsingR")
library(UsingR)
head(scrabble)

   piece points frequency
1      A      1         9
4      B      3         2
7      C      3         2
10     D      2         4
```

The variable *piece* shows the letter, and the variable *frequency* its respective frequency in the scrabble game.
Specifically, I would like to have on the X axis the letters, and on the Y axis the frequencies.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [`barplot()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html), *e.g.*:

```
barplot(scrabble$frequency, 
        names = scrabble$piece, 
        xlab = "Piece", 
        ylab = "Frequency", 
        main = "Letter Frequencies")
```

[image: Barplot]

To show all x-axis labels:

```
barplot(scrabble$frequency, 
        names = scrabble$piece, 
        xlab = "Piece", 
        ylab = "Frequency", 
        main = "Letter Frequencies", 
        las = 2, 
        cex.names = 0.5)
```

Comment: thank you Alex :)
I totally forgot I could give them NAMES :D

Comment: how do you keep barplot from skipping letters?